# How to create a object with nested objects in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Creating my first Django app ever here. I am having a problem with inserting my `Route` object. Here's my `models.py`:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    location_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location_lat = models.FloatField()
    location_log = models.FloatField() 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location_name

class Route(models.Model):
    route_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    route_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    origin_location = models.OneToOneField(Location, related_name="origin", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    destination_location = models.OneToOneField(Location, related_name="destination", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    waypoint1_location = models.OneToOneField(Location, related_name="waypoint1", on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    waypoint2_location = models.OneToOneField(Location, related_name="waypoint2", on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    route_duration = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.route_code
```

What I basically want is to have a `Route`, with *origin* and *destination* as mandatory and the waypoints optional.

First, I have a form page where the user creates the `Location` objects independently.

Then, I have another form page, where the user creates the Routes. It selects in the form the `Location` objects - one for *origin*, one for *destination* and optionally *waypoint1* and *waypoint2*

So, in that `Route` creation, I obviously don't want to create a new `Location`. It is already there. I only want to link the new `route` object to the already existing `location` objects.

My `serializers.py` is:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'

class RouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    origin_location = LocationSerializer(many=False, required=True)
    destination_location = LocationSerializer(many=False, required=True)
    waypoint1_location = LocationSerializer(many=False, required=False, read_only=True)
    waypoint2_location = LocationSerializer(many=False, required=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = '__all__'
```

The `route` JSON getting inserted is:

> {"route_code":"213123","origin_location":{"location_id":3,"location_name":"Tumut","location_lat":-35.31158,"location_log":148.21159},"destination_location":{"location_id":3,"location_name":"Tumut","location_lat":-35.31158,"location_log":148.21159}}

The error I am getting is:

> AssertionError at /api/route/\nThe `.create()` method does not support
>   writable nested fields by default.\nWrite an explicit `.create()`
>   method for serializer `planner.serializers.RouteSerializer`, or set
>   `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.\n\nRequest Method:
>   POST\nRequest URL: http://localhost:8000/api/route/\n

Seems like I need to write a `create()` function for my `RouteSerializer` but not sure how to approach it.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got this to work. Here are my changes:

`serializers.py`:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'

class RouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = '__all__'

class RouteReadSerializer(RouteSerializer):
    origin_location = LocationSerializer(read_only=True)
    destination_location = LocationSerializer(read_only=True)
    waypoint1_location = LocationSerializer(read_only=True)
    waypoint2_location = LocationSerializer(read_only=True)
```

`viewsets.py`

```
class RouteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Route.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RouteSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
         # Define your HTTP method-to-serializer mapping freely.
         # This also works with CoreAPI and Swagger documentation,
         # which produces clean and readable API documentation,
         # so I have chosen to believe this is the way the
         # Django REST Framework author intended things to work:
         if self.request.method in ['GET']:
             # Since the ReadSerializer does nested lookups
             # in multiple tables, only use it when necessary
             return RouteReadSerializer
         return RouteSerializer

class LocationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer
```

`models.py`

```
class Route(models.Model):
    route_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    route_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    origin_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="origin", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    destination_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="destination", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    waypoint1_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="waypoint1", on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    waypoint2_location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="waypoint2", on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    route_duration = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.route_code
```

I changed `OneToOneField` to `ForeignKey`. That actually makes more sense.

Thanks